# Include R chunk before YAML header in R markdown

Tags: r, r-markdown

I have my Rmd file in a different folder than the files it requires (e.g. `style.css`, `logo.png`, `header.html`)

I have tried to set the folder as working directory but these files are called before  I can even set it so the knit does not work because it does not find the files.

As it is:

````
---
title: foo title
author: foo
output: 
  html_document:
    includes:
      in_header: header.html
    css: style.css

---
```{r setup, include=FALSE, echo=FALSE}
  library(knitr)
opts_knit$set(root.dir = "~/path/to/folder/")
```
````

As I would like it to be and work:

````
```{r setup, include=FALSE, echo=FALSE}
  library(knitr)
opts_knit$set(root.dir = "~/path/to/folder/")
```
---
title: foo title
author: foo
output: 
  html_document:
    includes:
      in_header: header.html
    css: style.css

---
````

From the R script I want to render this report I call it using:

```
rmarkdown::render(input = report.rmarkdown.rmd.fpath,
                  output_file = output.html.report.fpath,
                  knit_root_dir = report.working.dpath)
```

But I Can imagine is happening the same regarding the moment in which the knit_root_dir is set.

Any idea how could this `header.html` and `style.css` be found if there is no way to put a chunk before the YAML header?

I could write the filepaths "manually" but I my header.html looks like:

```
<div><img src="logo.png" width="200px" align="right"></div>
```

and the `logo.png` would not be found anyways, right?

Thanks a lot!